# How do I iterate over this hash selectively?

Tags: ruby

```
{
  "menu": {
    "header": "menu",
    "items": [
      {"id": 27},
      {"id": 0, "label": "Label 0"},
      null,
      {"id": 93},
      {"id": 85},
      {"id": 54},
      null,
      {"id": 46, "label": "Label 46"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Above is the JSON that I am trying to iterate through.  Essentially, I would like to identify the value of key `"id"` if that hash also has a `"label"` key.

So the above would return `0` and `46` as well.

I am stuck here:

```
require 'json'

line = '{"menu": {"header": "menu", "items": [{"id": 27}, {"id": 0, "label": "Label 0"}, null, {"id": 93}, {"id": 85}, {"id": 54}, null, {"id": 46, "label": "Label 46"}]}}'
my_parse = JSON.parse(line)
items = my_parse['menu']['items'].compact.select { |item| item['label'] }

puts items.inject
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) to identify the elements that have both "id" and "label" then [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to pluck only the "ids".

```
hash = JSON.parse(your_json_string)
hash['menu']['items'].select { |h| h && h['id'] && h['label'] }.map {|h| h['id']}
# => [0, 46]
```

A more cleaned up version could look like this

```
def ids_with_label(json_str)
  hash = JSON.parse(json_str)
  items = hash['menu']['items']
  items_with_label = items.select { |h| h && h.include?('id') && h.include?('label') }
  ids = items_with_label.map { |h| h['id'] }
  ids
end

ids_with_label(your_json_string) # => [0, 46]
```

Comment: does the select just look for the word "label" in each element of the array?

Comment: @ppadru1: the example above actually checks that the value associated with the "label" key is truthy (not nil or false) - if you want to check only for the presence of any value for that key then use `h.include?("label")` instead of `h["label"]`.

Comment: I could probably simplify it by just doing 

`items = my_parse['menu']['items'].compact.select { |item| item['label'] }`

Comment: @ppadru1: yes, there are many ways to solve this problem - I chose a verbose one that explicitly solves it in separate parts.

Comment: I'm confused because `{"id"=>0, "label"=>"Label 0"}` is one element within the array, so how does it look through everything within this one element to check that there is at least one key named 'label'?

Comment: @ppadru1: `h.include?('id') && h.include?('label')`

Comment: ppadru1, you can use any of three `Hash` methods to determine if a hash `h` has a key `k`:  `h.include?(k)`, `h.key?(k)` or `h.has_key?(k)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what you want exactly:

```
items = my_parse['menu']['items'].compact.select { |item| item.has_key?('label') }.map{ |item| item['id'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a temporary array:

```
my_parse['menu']['items'].each_with_object([]) { |o,a|
  a << o['id'] if o && o.key?('id') && o.key?('label') }
  #=> [0, 46]
```